# Syntax error in date in expression in Access 2016

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am not very good with Access and I am creating a simple booking database wherein the available times will exclude times that were already booked.

I am following a tutorial and it was already working, then suddenly I am getting the error: Syntax error in date in expression

```
oRS.FindFirst "[ApptTime] Between #" & i - TimeValue("00:00:05") & _
  "# And #" & i + TimeValue("00:00:05") & "#"
```

where oRS is set as DAO.Recordset and it contains the fields CounselorID, ApptDate, ApptTime

I expect to have a list of available times that do not include the time that have been booked already.

Comment: What is `i`? -- Try it first in a query: [How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1099570/3820271)

Comment: What is printed if you replace `oRS.FindFirst` with `Debug.Print`?

Answer (score 0):

If **i** is some time of the day, use *DateAdd* to set the interval:

```
oRS.FindFirst "[ApptTime] Between DateAdd("s", -5, i) And DateAdd("s", 5, i)
```